# How to install full linux to a usb drive like unetbootin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, app

I have recently looked into linux as my mac is currently at 10.12 and I need to run newer apps but currently cannot get a new computer. I have decided to move to linux but I don't want to touch the hard drive lest it be damaged. For that reason, an install to usb seems fine. However, I don't want to install from a traditional installer like ubuntu's (in live mode). I want to use a system set up like unetbootin, where I can see the disk name (sort of) and I know that my mac os part is safe. My computer supports booting from usb. As for the distro, anything based on the latest ubuntu (so I can run apps) would be good but I would like a full installation to usb drive, not live or persistent live. I have a 16GB usb, if that helps. Is this possible???

Comment: If you want a *full installation to usb drive, not live or persistent live* then do a full installation in which the target drive is your USB drive. It's that simple and with the same method to install to any other internal drive. Now, 16GB is probably not enough in this day and age for a mainstream distro (e.g. Linux Mint installer now refuses to install anywhere with less than 16GB plus a few MBs; knowing that any "16GB" drive is typically less than the advertised capacity you may have a problem right there from the start).

Comment: I suggest getting a good proper USB drive, not a flash memory stick, with a lot more capacity, USB 3.x and as fast as you can get. The performance of ANY current OS running from an USB stick is just horrible to point of being unusable.

Comment: I was thinking about a virtual machine before but my computer (old os) only can run virtualbox 5.2 and ubuntu 22 flickers. Any way I can fix this?